# webapp configuration in spring mvc read from database

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm struggling to find some idea, tutorial or sample how to put some of the configuration of the webapp into database. There will be static configuration put in properties files like database connection, but there is some configuration which can be changed like email account, facebook account and best location for this in the database. That configuration should be loaded as soon as possible when webapp starts. Ideally all the configuration should be in some bean named Configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When a Spring webapp starts, Spring instantiates and injects all its beans. Once the beans are instantiated and injected, if a bean has [a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-postconstruct-and-predestroy-annotations), it calls this method.

So you just have to define such a method, read the config from the database and store it in the bean (if you want it to be cached).

Inject this bean everywhere you need access to the configuration properties.